# Why is this proxy not working in angular?

Tags: angular, npm, proxy, routes, port

Hello this is my `npm start` command in `package.json`

```
"start": "ng serve --port 4201 --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --host 0.0.0.0",
```

My backend server is running on `8081` port. So if I go to `http://localhost:8081/api/overview` I am getting a json output(not relevant to question).

This is my `proxy.conf.json` file

```
{
  "/api/overview": {
    "target": "http://localhost:8081/",
    "pathRewrite": {"api/overview": "assets/api/overview.json"},
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

In my service, I am calling the url like this

```
return this._httpClient.get<OverviewData>('/api/overview').pipe(first());
```

Now when I run angular and go to `http://localhost:4201` in browser and my app starts, this above line of code tries to fetch url `http://localhost:4201/api/overview` instead of `http://localhost:8081/api/overview`. How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: In Network tab, what ever the port you configure, it shows the port the UI running.
But internally Angular manages it to redirect to server port. Like in your case. even though in network tab it shows http://localhost:4201/api/overview. Internally it should query to http://localhost:8081/api/overview.

Comment: I am actually getting the error in console.log also saying that it was trying to fetch 4201/api/overview and it failed since well no endpoint exists like that.